# what distributions are limited with power transformation?

Tags: machine-learning, distributions, normal-distribution, data-transformation

if I have a rough bell shaped distribution but with a heavy skewness, I could "correct" that by transforming that distribution similar to a normal distribution via power transformation

Can power transformations be used on any distribution to transform it similarly to a normal distribution?

what are the limits?

Comment: Could you please clarify what you mean by "similar to a normal distribution"?  Only odd integer powers can even possibly create a normal distribution, because only those can have negative values--and any normal distribution assigns *some* probability to negative values. This leads one to suspect you are interested in *approximating* distributions with normal distributions, but that begs the questions of how good should the approximation be and how do you measure how good it is. Unless you can be specific about these issues, your question will be too vague to answer.

Comment: well, it's for data processing for deep learning. So a very "close" approximation is not needed. Just as long as it would "appear" to be an approximation to the normal distribution, then it's fine.